# Is the splitting field of $x^2+1$ over $\Bbb Z_2$ is $\{0,1,i,1+i\}$.

Tags: finite-fields

I am not sure about my answer.
Since x^2+1 is reducible with respect to Z2 but X^2-1 is irreducible with respect to Z2 so I made this finite field {0,1,i,1+i} nd said it as the splitting field of above polynomial.
apologize for typing mistakes.

Comment: ???? $\Bbb Z_2$ **is** a field.

Comment: sorry for mistakes in typing. Read again my question.

Comment: ???? In $\Bbb Z_2$, $1=-1$ so $x^2+1 = x^2-1$.

Comment: $x^2-1 = (x+1)(x-1)$, so *never* is irreducible.

Comment: @Martín-Blas Pérez Pinilla, actually I had studied that if x^2-1 has no zeros with respect to Z2 then it is reducible in case of Z2

Comment: I mean irreducible

Comment: Well, $x=1$ is definitely a zero of $x^2+1$ in $\Bbb{Z}_2$, because
$$1^2+1=2=0.$$

Comment: @AsMa, $x^2-1=x ^2+1$ *has* zeros in $\Bbb Z_2$.

Comment: ok, I get it thanks

Answer (score 2):

No. The splitting field of $x^2+1$ over $\mathbf Z_2$ is $\mathbf Z_2$ itself since $x^2+1=(x+1)^2$ has $1$ as a double root in $\mathbf Z_2$.

Comment: The roots of above polynomial are i and -i and Z2 doen't contain these roots.

Comment: @AsMa, stop thinking that you are in $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$.

Comment: @Martín-Blas Pérez Pinilla, I got your above point but I am still confused that how Z2 is itself its splitting field can u please explain it little more.Thanks

Comment: @AsMa, is this answer: $x^2+1 = (x+1)^2$

Comment: As we know that splitting field of a polynomial is the smallest field extension of a field in which the polynomial has linear factors.

Comment: @AsMa: Please see what I've added to my answer.

Comment: @AsMa, what can be smaller than the *same* field?

Comment: nothing, but what are the roots of x^2+1 ? My question is that Z2 doesn't contain i and -i it only contains 0 and 1 which are not the roots of x^2+1.

Comment: well, just like x^2+1 has splitting field C over R because C is the extension of R and it contain its roots i and -i .

Comment: @AsMa If you define $i$ as a root of $x^2+1$, then $\Bbb Z2$ _does_ contain $i$ and $-i$ - except in this case $1=i=-i$.

Comment: @AsMa, $1$ **is** a root (double) of $x^2+1$.